# how to change button text dynamically for every 3 sec in android?

Tags: android

in my application i want to change button text for every 3 sec.

Answer (score 5):

Set up a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to run a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) every 3 seconds. The [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) only has to call the button's [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) method to change the button's text. You would have to do this within the UI thread, so you should use **post** to run a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) object that will perform the update an the correct thread.

For example, in the following activity, the letter "A" is added to the button's text every three seconds:

```
public class ButtonTest extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button subject = new Button(this);
        subject.setLayoutParams((new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
        subject.setText("A");
        setContentView(subject);

        Timer timing = new Timer();
        timing.schedule(new Updater(subject), 3000, 3000);
    }

    private static class Updater extends TimerTask {
        private final Button subject;

        public Updater(Button subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            subject.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    subject.setText(subject.getText() + "A");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you won't be able to update UI thread without a Handler.

Comment: well you derive from TimerTask anyway so pass a reference in your own function

Comment: hi,please provide some sample code for Timmer

Comment: hi, please see my updated post with a complete example

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this neat little example: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

All you need is a handler and a task! Within the Task do your actions (setting the text) and set up the next handler event using `Handler.postDelayed`.

But keep the following in mind: I would strongly advise you to set up the first timer event in the activity's `onResume()` method and **NOT** in its `onCreate` method. Also, remove (cancel) your handler in `onPause()`!

To understand the meaning of this, have a look at an activity's [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).

That way you prevent to have anything happening while your activity is in the background and not visible!

Answer (score 1):

@deepthi: here is an detail example to to display text in a button at specific time interval

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {

private static final long GET_DATA_INTERVAL = 2000;
int images[] = {R.drawable.kanya,R.drawable.kumba};
private String[] textfirst={"nsc","bsc","nasadq","tcs","mds","mac","manipal"};

int index = 0;
ImageView img;
Button btn;
Handler hand = new Handler();
Handler hand1 = new Handler();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    hand1.postDelayed(run1, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);      
}

Runnable run1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        btn.setText(textfirst[index++]);
        if (index == textfirst.length)
            index = 0;
        hand1.postDelayed(run1, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncTask` you can do something like this to update a `Button` named button1

```
private class UpdateButton extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int i = 0;
        while ( true ) {
            publishProgress("" + i++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return (Void)null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        button1.setText(values[0]);
    }       
}
```

to start button1 update

```
(new UpdateButton()).execute((Void)null);
```